# Сколько разделов может быть в ОС

Tags: c++, winapi

Использовал функцию `GetLogicalDevices` и возник вопрос, сколько может быть логических разделов в *Windows*? 26 - как и количество букв в английском языке или 32 - количество бит в `DWORD` типе, а может еще больше?

Comment: именованных - 26. Но на самом деле больше, просто к ним нужно уметь обращаться. Но это в все в том случае, если у Вас ОС == винда. В других осях подобных вопросов не возникает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дисков с буквами - 24, так как буквы A и B намертво прибиты к дисководам для дискет.

Прочих дисков может быть сколько угодно, так как том можно примонтировать к любой папке NTFS.

И да, в DWORD 32 бита, а не 34.

Comment: по крайней мере 10 винда позволяет использовать букву А в качестве диска. Так что ничего не прибито.

Comment: @КоVadim - тут как повезет с дистрибутивом.

Comment: нет, тут как раз зависит от того, что думает железо о дискете. Если она есть (физически или только в воображении биоса), то конечно же нельзя будет присвоить. В современных материнках ее давно нет и проблем нет.

Comment: @KoVadim `В современных материнках ее давно нет` звучит несколько странно.

Comment: имеется ввиду разъем для подключения дисковода.

Comment: так функция GetLogicalDevices возвращает 32 значения, если больше 32 разделов, то как быть?

Comment: Эта функция немного уже устаревшая. В любом случае, если раздел есть, но ему буква не присвоена, Вы о нем не узнаете этой функцией.

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо, если бы вы еще про потоки помогли бы до конца, цены бы вам не было =)